# mat-select required cannot be reset

Tags: angular, angular-material

Each formGroup using a mat-select as the only required field cannot be reset with FormGroup.reset() because validators are not reset

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material7-template-matselect-required?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

when submitting, the first field is empty & mark as error...

Only solution that worked for me is to use ngIf to regenerate form but its not really nice for the user that see an empty html for a sec...

Any other solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: That is ur problem : `when submitting, the first field is empty & mark as error` ?

Comment: yes, sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SetValidators to make the Validators required to nullvalidator

```
  this.group.controls['select'].setValidators([Validators.nullValidator])
  this.group.controls['select'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: Reset was already working, what does not work is when you submit, the form is emptied but the drop-down list shows an error whereas it should not

Comment: So what is your expected result can you elaborate little more!

Comment: On your example, What I am doing is : Fill select, fill input, click submit. 
What is happening : select is emptied and show an error
What is expected : select is emptied but show no error as a new form

Comment: check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material7-template-matselect-required-vrbtqw

Answer (score 2):

As there is already an accepted answer, I can suggest a less added lines there.

That is a bit-known bug of `Material`, as a workaround you can do add an `ElementReference` to your `form` tag `#f="ngForm"`:

```
<form [formGroup]="quickFileForm" (ngSubmit)="saveQuickFileForm()" #f="ngForm">
```

Then add a `@ViewChild` decorator to your TS part that refer to the tag in your form:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  group = new FormGroup({
    select: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    input: new FormControl()
  });

  @ViewChild('f') myForm;

   ....
   ....
}
```

Do not forget to import it above from `@angular/core`. Then merely add:

```
this.myForm.resetForm();
```

to your method:

```
submit() {
    if(this.group.valid) {
      const obj = new MyObj();
      Object.assign(obj, this.group.value);

      this.survey.push(obj);
      this.myForm.resetForm(); // <-- Here you add it.
      return;
    }

    alert('not valid, try again')
  }
```

Comment: Yes I found a post talking about this answer but I got an error when I tried this solution : Cannot read property 'resetForm' of undefined